# How to make ipa file from react native cli for testing?

Tags: xcode, react-native, ipa

1. Do I need a paid developer account from apple?

2)IF no, then how to do it?

I have Xcode installed.

This is very unclear to me
https://reactnative.dev/docs/publishing-to-app-store

Answer (score 0):

You can test through Apple's test flight.

Please refer to the [official document for the contents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-your-app-for-beta-testing-and-releases).

If you want to automate repetitive distributions, you can use the following library.

[circleci document](https://circleci.com/)